# Symfony2 Vendors bundle route

Tags: symfony, routes

I made a bundle that should provide easy "drop file" style upload. The problem is, when I install the bundle in a symfony2 project, I need to provide upload file route to my page.

Drop upload bundle routing:

```
pi_flex_drop_uploader_receiver:
    pattern: /drop_upload
    defaults: { _controller: PIFlexDropUploaderBundle:Upload:upload }
```

However, in my project that should use the bundle:

Twig template fragment:

```
$('textarea').dropLoad({
    uploadScript: "{{ path('pi_flex_drop_uploader_receiver') }}",

    onFileUploadEnd: function(value, data) {
        console.log(data.data.url);
    }
});
```

Throws an exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Route "pi_flex_drop_uploader_receiver" does not exist.") in PIFlexBlogBundle:Page:admin_article.html.twig at line 15.

Why is this so? Do I have cross-bundle routing access? Can template in one bundle access other bundle's routing? How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: Yes, bundles can see other bundle routes. Can you see your route when you run `php app/console router:debug` from your project root?

Comment: I just checked, no I can't, routes from that bundle aren't visible at all. I just installed bundle and added it to AppKernel.php. Do I need to do anything more? Do I need to manually include it's routing in my app?

Comment: Ok, thanks to your `router:debug` suggestion I figured I needed to manually import that bundle's routing in my app. I was assuming it does it automatically for all bundles in AppKernel!

Comment: add it as an answer and accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Jaitsu's comment, I figured out just adding bundle to AppKernel wasn't enough. I had to import it's routing in global symfony app routing file.